# Android SQLite Wildcards

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to query with a wildcard element to search my SQLite table for entries with an element at any position in a specific variable.

```
public String[] getCheckoutEntry(String title, String ISBN)
{
//Wild card Syntax
String titleWildCard = "%" + title + "%";
String ISBNWildCard = "%" + ISBN + "%";
//Query
String query = "select USER,AUTHOR,DATE,CALL_NUMBER,COUNT from CHECKOUT where TITLE = ? or ISBN = ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {titleWildCard, ISBNWildCard};
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
```

I've checked half a dozen answers on Stack Overflow already and everyone suggests simply appending a "%" to my variable, as seen above. When I try the above code, my program simply interprets titleWildCard including the % as the search query and tries to find % in the table.

If I take out the "%" then the program runs without issue except that it only searches for the exact term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `=` operator with `LIKE` to make `%` behave like wildcard:

```
... where TITLE LIKE ? or ISBN LIKE ?
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)