# sqlite android concatenation not works

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to make query from table with search by first and last names columns.
When input simple name with 1 word (like "Tom" ) all fine. Query with 2 or more search keywords not works. F.e "Anny Lee". Is there possible way to search by concatenated contacts_table.first_name and contacts_table.last_name value in DB table? The part of query below:

```
AND ( (contacts_table.first_name || contacts_table.last_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%') OR (....))
```

Cant implement OR statement in right way.

Comment: Your SQL statement seems to have incorrect logic. Have you tried: `AND ( (contacts_table.first_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%') OR (contacts_table.last_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%') OR (....))`

Comment: @Bonatti I need implement this part of query "OR (....)". First part is correct at all. Your example will be work like mine, because will check by f.name OR l.name. Need to make search like this -  String name = f.name + l.name;  "name" LIKE "KEYWORD".

Comment: Ohhh, I misunderstood. Cant you just append the two Strings and query that? (first check for null, and replace it for empty instead, then append, such as `if(contacts_table.first_name==null{contacts_table.first_name=""}...repeat for lastname...) String fullName =contacts_table.first_name+contacts_table.last_name;`. Then on SQL< query for `fullName`

Comment: (contacts_table.first_name + ' ' + contacts_table.last_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%') -  with this case always returns empty Cursor.

Comment: @Bonatti, I dont understand))) I ment, that need to search in table by some name, but in table have 2 columns - f.name and last name. So, will be possible implement search like ( "contacts_table.first_name" + "contacts_table.last_name"  LIKE  KEYWORD), not by f.name or l.name. ) Just like this "(contacts_table.first_name + ' ' + contacts_table.last_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%')", but it not works.

Comment: Do you want a data row, for a record that has BOTH first name and last name? So, 0-"Bob the Builder" and 1-"Sara the Explorer", searching for `ob` would return 0, and `the` would return NONE, and `o` would return 0 and 1? If so, a LIKE must be contained, the more parameters you have, the more filters you are setting. As far as I can see, your problem is mixing Java with SQL. Prepare the statement, and then execute it. Remember that a space has to be replaced, by `%` so, your query should be `LIKE %Bo%der` would return from `Border` and `Bob Builder`.

Comment: @Bonatti, "Do you want a data row, for a record that has BOTH first name and last name?" - Yea. F.e  name in bd "Jane Vane" - f.name "Jane", l.name "Key". Case 1: any letter, that in Both columns - must return 1; Case 2: keywords like "Jane", "Vane", "Jane Vane", "Jane V", " ane Van" and like this -  must return 1;  I don't know is it possible in sqlite or how to implement it. That's why asked on Stack.

Comment: Yes, it can. [Here is documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) and [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878482/android-sqlite-wildcards), [or another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592853/wildcard-not-working-in-sqlite). Basically, query this: `"%"+"firstName"+"%"+"lastName"+"%"`